# Why is this simple jsp program is NOT running?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

As we know every jsp program there is a servlet behind the jsp page. I have used a jsp page to make a form (its a very small form), and in the same jsp i used scriptlet tags and made a way to get the inserted form data, and display it using out.print(). but the problem is it when i run it, the form is displayed., but when i submit is, it doesn't recognize the servlet page (error coming as "The requested resource is not available"). i will put the code below., please help me friends to solve this problem. thank you.
i did this in netbeans.
jsp page name is- "hello.jsp"
the servlet page name behind the jsp page is: "hello_jsp.java".

```
<html> 
<head><title>IF...ELSE Example</title></head> 
<body>  
<form action="hello_jsp" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="y"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

<% 
  if(request.getParameter("y")!=null) { 
    String s = request.getParameter("y"); 
    if(s.equals("hello")){
    out.print("welcome"+s);
  }else{
    out.print("not welcome");
  }}
%> 

</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: *i used scriptlet tags* why?

Comment: what is `hello_jsp`? Is it a JSP or Servlet?

Comment: i don't want to pass the form data to another servlet, i want to get this done from the same servlet that is behind the jsp. so i had to use scriptlets.

Comment: @user3218114 hello_jsp.java is a servlet, i didn't put that namee., it automatically generates, when i name my jsp page as hello.jsp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you need to change

```
<form action="hello_jsp" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="hello.jsp" method="post">
<!--               ^---- change is here -->
```

The externally-accesible resource is the `jsp`, not the servlet. (By default, I'm sure some config-fu could change that.)

Or, of course, if the page is supposed to submit to itself, don't include `action` at all. The default is to submit to the current page.

```
<form method="post">
```